# How can I force an app to uninstall?

Tags: applications, ipod-touch, jailbreak, macos

I just installed an app that was a waste of my time. The problem is, when I long-pressed the app to delete it, it didn't show an (x).  How can I delete it?  I've looked through the settings.  I'm kind of new to iPods so if this is simple, just say it bluntly.

Comment: What version of iOS are you using? Also, is the iPod jailbroken?

Comment: @mahnax I'm using iOS 4.x and it is jb.

Comment: Did you download it with Cydia?

Comment: @mahnax Yes, I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You open up Cydia>Manage and then delete the app. Enjoy!